# How to replace a string in a file with a multi-line value from a shell variable

Tags: bash, macos, sed

I'm trying to replace a portion of a plist (using Mac OS High Sierra) using a script.

I have a variable set to the output of a for loop and said output looks like this when I echo or printf it:

```
<array>
 <dict>
  <key>cfurl_string</key>
  <string>/Applications/Launchpad.app</string>
 </dict>
 <dict>
  <key>cfurl_string</key>
  <string>/Applications/Safari.app</string>
 </dict>
 <dict>
  <key>cfurl_string</key>
  <string>/Applications/Pages.app</string>
 </dict>
 <dict>
  <key>cfurl_string</key>
  <string>/Applications/Numbers.app</string>
 </dict>
 <dict>
  <key>cfurl_string</key>
  <string>/Applications/Keynote.app</string>
 </dict>
 <dict>
  <key>cfurl_string</key>
  <string>/Applications/Photos.app</string>
 </dict>
 <dict>
  <key>cfurl_string</key>
  <string>/Applications/iMovie.app</string>
 </dict>
 <dict>
  <key>cfurl_string</key>
  <string>/Applications/GarageBand.app</string>
 </dict>
 <dict>
  <key>cfurl_string</key>
  <string>/Applications/Microsoft Word.app</string>
 </dict>
 <dict>
  <key>cfurl_string</key>
  <string>/Applications/Microsoft Excel.app</string>
 </dict>
</array>
```

I also have a plist that I've set as a template so that I can find the value "" and replace that with the output I showed above. If i use a regular string like "test" or "word" it works completely find, but if I run the command with the value i.e.

```
sed -e "s|<array></array>|${test}|" dmt.plist > dmtfinished.plist
```

it gives me the error: unescaped newline inside substitute pattern

I've tried as much as I could for the past few hours with the same result. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: post the expected result

Comment: what I posted above is the expected result, i have a plist with a line set to "<array></array>". I want to replace that with the variable output that I posted above; the first set of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do it with `sed`:

```
sed -e '/<array><\/array>/{r /dev/stdin' -e ';d;}' file <<<"$test"
```

where we use the [`r filename` command](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-Read-text-from-a-file) to append the text from filename `/dev/stdin` when we encounter the `<array></array>` string. We feed the contents of the variable `$test` to [`/dev/stdin`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Redirections) via a [here-string](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/redirection#here_strings) redirection. After appending we delete the pattern space.

Also note we had to break the `sed` program in two expressions, the reason being that `r` command has to end with a newline. The alternative is to write the program in several lines:

```
sed '/<array><\/array>/ {
    r /dev/stdin
    d
}' file <<<"$test"
```

Comment: i'm getting a extra characters at end of d command error when I run it

Comment: Oh, try adding `;`, or the multi-line version (see my edit).

Comment: this worked, but I'm not understanding why. I need to read up on what you did because It's not blatantly obvious. It also didn't save like I wanted to, but thank you none the less. You've put me in the right direction

Comment: This is a classic `sed` pattern to append text from a shell variable. Probably not obvious when seeing it for the first time, but I tried to explain the gist of it. The trick is to use the `r` command, combined with `/dev/stdin` file (available in `bash`) and the here-string.

Comment: Added a few links, hope they'll lead you further on the path of sed/bash magic discovery. :)

Comment: Thanks a bunch , you've been very helpful :)